# assertion fails in scala cucumber test

Tags: scala, cucumber, bdd

I am writing automation test case for scala code using BDD cucumber. I have a method in my util class as follows

```
def getStatus(): String = {
    val url = myUrl
    val result = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString
    val json = result.parseJson.asJsObject().getFields("status")
    return json(0).toString()
  }
```

This gives  me value of status field from my model. I call this method in my Given condition and try to assert as follows.

```
var statusResult = ""
  Given("""^Check if data exists"") { () =>

    statusResult = myData.geStatus();
    assert(statusResult == "UP")

}
```

When I print statusResult varaible above assert  I can see its value is printed as "UP" but assert fails on running the test case.  How can I solve it?

Comment: What's the message of failing assertion?

Comment: it is just showing assertion failed and line number at which assert is there